# Requesting a word - "Progressing" - "Slow but gradually moving."

Tags: single-word-requests

Looking for a word that fits "progression" or "slow but gradually moving", using this for a list of uncompleted factors that have multiple states.

For example:

- Finished.
- Developing.
- Progressing. (Would be active currently, but not finished.)

Another solution to this would be a word, for something that has been finished to a certain point but is still currently active and developing.

*Edited: Its for a list, its going to be used for managing the current state in which said "project" has reached.

Comment: Please add context.  Are you asking about software development, a baby that has just been born, or the first draft of a novel?  Or what?

Comment: "Glacially progressing"? :-)

Comment: I was hoping for something that would be more direct in the terms of the "ending" but still going part. It has the still going part, but doesn't quite fit the "has ended" part, and that it would be ideal to have it beone word instead of two.

Answer (score 1):

• Finished.
• Developing.
• Evolving.

Shows that it will change . . . but slowly.

Comment: Which came first, your user name or your answer?? +1

Answer (score 0):

"Loose ends" describes your list well and possibly needs no further description, but might be too colloquial if the list is meant for the benefit of much higher levels of management.

Answer (score 0):

How about "maturing" (fully formed but being incrementally embellished)

Answer (score 0):

The second meaning of “[gestating](http://www.yourdictionary.com/gestate), the transitive verb, is:
“To conceive and develop in the mind”

and “To develop gradually” as an intransitive one.

(from ‘Your Dictionary’)

There's also the adjective derived from it "[gestational](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gestational)."

Although there’s some overlap with “Developing” (not to mention potential confusion with its biological meaning), it does capture the notion of “gradual”:

Finished

Developing

Gestating (Gestational)